# Making a desktop LaTeX editor ground up

Tags: compiling, editors, mac

Have been considering trying to make a desktop LaTeX editor (similar to Lyx or texmaker) for personal use as a long-term side project, also hoping to pick up some things along the way.

I'm largely unsure where to start, was considering using codemirror and then an electron wrapper? Would love some pointers, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure, this is the right SE for this. But why building something new, if there is emacs with AuCTeX out there? ;)

Comment: Writing an editor is off-topic for us, I think: the technical stuff you need is general programming, not LaTeX-specific. That said, I suspect this is also far too broad as  question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @PauloCereda has the same long-term project, ArTeXmis, a new desktop LaTeX editor. Maybe you could join efforts ;) But as others said, this is off-topic here.